# Getting a start and stop time points of returning HTTP codes by HTTP endpoint, in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, promql

Let's assume we have a time range of day - 00:00 - 23:59 and HTTP endpoint(which is being probed by Blackbox-exporter) returns status codes:

- from 00:00 to 7:00 endpoint was returning 200
- then from 7:00 to 7:05 was returning 500
- then from 7:05 to 20:00 was returning 200
- then from 20:00 to 20:10 was returning 404
- and from 20:10 to 23:59 was returning 200

Can I reflect it somehow in Prometheus, i.e. when one code ends up being returned and another one started? And maybe it's possible to output somehow in Grafana on a time-range plot?

Comment: No, by HTTP endpoint I mean custom HTTP service, e.g. website, in which uptime and downtime we are interested in.  But blackbox-exporter is involved in probing this service. Sorry for the confusion, not a Prometheus HTTP module calls endpoints, but blackbox-exporter does, I updated the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is just to visualize status code, you don't need some clever promQL query for this.

You can simply create "State timeline" panel with `probe_http_status_code` query.

To make this panel show data in understandable way:

1. Expand query options (under query), select Legend: Custom, and put `{{instance}}` into it.
2. Go to Panel options: Standard options > Color scheme > Single color.
3. Value mappings: add HTTP codes with corresponding colors. You can make mappings single value or range based.

In the result you'll get something like this:
[image]